# 3 game cards per slide in a bootstrap carousel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, dynamic, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel on a page, where I have 3 game cards per one slide, but they are hardcoded. How can I make them dynamic? I need to take game cards from my db. This is what I have now:

```
<div id="carousel" class="carousel-inner thumb-inner">
  <div class="active item">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 slide1 slider-div">
      <div class="game-card">Some content here</div>
      <div class="game-card">Some content here</div>
      <div class="game-card">Some content here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 slide1 slider-div">
      <div class="game-card">Some content here</div>
      <div class="game-card">Some content here</div>
      <div class="game-card">Some content here</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What is the right way to put a ruby code here? My thoughts were smth. like this:

```
<div class="active item">
  <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-xs-12 slide1 slider-div">
    <% Game.all.each_with_index do |game, index| %>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
        <%= game.title %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
</div>
```

But this will give me all game card on a slide. What is the correct way to make 3 game card per one slide? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of `limit` and `offset` here to get 3 records at a time. For example:

```
Game.offset(0).limit(3)  # first 3 items
Game.offset(3).limit(3)  # next 3 items
```

---

If the Game table only has a small number of records that fit comfortably in memory, you could also do something like this:

```
items = Game.all.to_a  # do this once to load up all the records
items.shift(3)         # call repeatedly to get the next 3 items
```

This has the advantage that you can randomise the items upfront e.g. `Game.order("RANDOM()").to_a`